# Keeping data from a class that goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, smart-pointers

I am working with a class "foo" from an external library, that calculates and stores large amounts of data. After it finished its calculation, I want to retain just the array of the results data, which makes up about half of the size of "foo". Foo provides a pointer to the result data with the function `RawResultsArray()` with typeid `PNSt3__17complexIdEE`.
Until now, I have been doing this:

```
int N; //length of the results array
complex<double> * results_to_keep;

{
    foo myFoo;

    myFoo.findResults();

    results_to_keep = new complex<double>[N];
    for (auto i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        results_to_keep[i] = myFoo.RawResultsArray()[i];
    }
}
//work with results_to_keep in further code...
delete [] results_to_keep;
//do other memory intensive stuff in further code...
```

I am however working with limited memory and can not afford to have the `results_to_keep` array and the `myFoo` class allocated at the same time. Is there a way to keep the data of length `N*sizeof(complex<double>)` at `myFoo.RawResultsArray()` after going out of scope at line 14, without temporarily allocating the full array again?

I unsuccessfully played around with smart pointers. I think my best try is:

```
std::unique_ptr<complex<double>[]> results_to_keep;
{
    foo myFoo;
    myFoo.findResults();

    std::unique_ptr<complex<double>[]> temp (move(myFoo.RawResultsArray());
    results_to_keep = move(temp);
}
//work with results_to_keep in further code...
results_to_keep.reset();
//do other memory intensive stuff in further code...
```

This way, `results_to_keep` does retain the data successfully, but I can not free the memory again with the last line. It throws `malloc: *** error for object 0x106000010: pointer being freed was not allocated`.

Additional info: `typeid(myFoo.RawResultsArray()).name()` gives out `PNSt3__17complexIdEE`. I am using the Apple LLVM 8.1 compiler.

Comment: In what way is this program written in C?

Comment: You need to publish definition of class `foo` then we can say if it is possible to move that data out of it,

Comment: How about copying that data into a buffer you actually own?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<complex<double>[]> temp (move(myFoo.RawResultsArray());
    results_to_keep = move(temp);` Why do you want to create `temp` ? Why not move `myFoo.RawResultsArray()`  directly to `results_to_keep`? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @mutex36: Now actually read the question.

Comment: @svasa: `move` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition my bad. Still thats the only sane way of doing this I imagine. You can't just take over a buffer you didn't allocate. It might get deallocated by "foo".

Comment: Your code will only work on Mondays, at 10:15. results_to_keep is still pointing to memory that has been deallocated when foo goes out of scope. Also, you can use c++filt from the command line to get the type of the variable : `c++filt PNSt3__17complexIdEE`

Comment: @mutex36: It does get deallocated by "foo", as shown in the question. That's the problem.

Comment: @mdavezac: No need; it's a `complex<double>*`.

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry.

If a `foo` "owns" the data it encapsulates, fully manages the lifetime of that data, and does not provide you with a means to "steal" that data, there is no alternative to copying it into a new buffer.

Comment: If you tell us what `foo` _really_ is, we may be able to come up with a real-world workaround. Although I wouldn't hold my breath :)